# How to hide the push node in mongooseIM-Push from other users

Tags: mongoose-im

I am using MongooseIM 3.1 version along with mongooseim push feature. According to the guide, we need to create a new node for push and then enable it. I have following doubts regarding the same.

1. How can I hide this node (node created due to push feature) from other users, since this node is not relevant to other users. I just want to make it hide from other users via service discovery stanzas.
2. IS there any harm if anyone knows our node push name?

Answer (score 0):

Answering to your first questions, you can create the push node in the following way:

```
<iq type='set' to='pubsub.mypubsub.com' id='create1'>
  <pubsub xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub'>
    <create node='punsub_node_for_my_private_iphone' type='push'/>
    <configure>
      <x xmlns='jabber:x:data' type='submit'>
        <field var='FORM_TYPE' type='hidden'>
          <value>http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#node_config</value>
        </field>
        <field var='pubsub#access_model'>
          <value>whitelist</value>
        </field>
        <field var='pubsub#publish_model'>
          <value>publishers</value>
        </field>
       </x>
    </configure>
  </pubsub>
</iq>
```

Please note the node configuration. The `access_model` is set to `whitelist` so only whitelisted users can access (see the node). It's OK to leave it empty, then only owner will see it.

Also there is the `publish_model` set to `publishers` which means that only owner or users with affiliation `publish` or `publish_only` can publish to this node.

MongooseIM generates publish request on behalf of the node's owner so in fact you don't have to add any other user as a publisher to the push node.

Let me know if his helps and answers your questions.